# Java member variables as associative array like AS3

Tags: java, actionscript-3, associative-array

In ActionScript 2 and 3, we can access a member variable of a class like it is in an associative array.

for eg.,

```
//AS3 Code    
private var tempvar:String="Hello";

    function printString()
    {
       trace(this.tempvar);
      trace(this[tempvar]);// would print the same as above
    }
```

I was wondering if the same is possible in Java as well.

The reason I need this is because, I have some variables like the following in my java code

```
//java code
private String var_1, var_2, var_3, var_4;
```

To access these variables, I have to write 4 different statements

```
//java code
var_1="SomeValue1";
var_2="SomeValue2";
var_3="SomeValue3";
var_4="SomeValue4";
```

If it is in AS3, I could have done something like this

```
//AS3 Code
for( var i=1; i<=4;i++)
{
 this["var_"+i]="SomeValue"+i;
}
```

I'll be a much happy coder if someone could let me know how to do the same in Java.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to refactor your Java code...

You can use a `Map<String, String>` to achieve that.

Comment: +1 This is really the way to go for storing values: Use a Map. For accessing methods, you'd have to use the reflections API.

Answer (score 3):

In theory, you could do this with the reflection API. In practice, you would not use this style of coding in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array, Ex:

```
String[] myVars = new String[4];
for(int i = 0; i < myVars.length; i++)
{
 myVars[i]="SomeValue"+i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use beanutils:
http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/

```
BeanUtils.setProperty(yourVarsObject, "foo", "bar");
```

This would call the setFoo("bar") at yourVarsObject